# Apex AggregateResult show Distinct Values only

Tags: apex, soql, aggregateresult

I am searching for the equivalent of a SOQL DISTINCT to use within my AggregateResult query below.

I would like to group my results using a field called "Servicer_Code__c".  Would any one know if this is even possible?

Thanks in advance!

```
    private List<CoverageTeamMember> getCoverageTeam( Account account ) {
    List<CoverageTeamMember> result = this.getStaticCoverageTeam( account );

    for ( AggregateResult records : [ 
        SELECT Id, Servicer_Department_Name__c role, Servicer__r.Id name,    
    Servicer__r.Name actualname, Servicer__r.Email__c email, 
    Servicer__r.Work_Phone__c phone, Active__c a, Servicer_Code__c sc
        FROM Policy__c
        WHERE Account__c = :account.Id AND 
            Servicer_Department_Name__c != null AND
            Servicer__c != null AND
            Active__c = True
        GROUP BY Id, Servicer_Department_Name__c, Servicer__r.Id, Servicer__r.Name, Servicer__r.Email__c, Servicer__r.Work_Phone__c, Active__c, Servicer_Code__c
    ] ) {
        result.add( new CoverageTeamMember( records ) );
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that cannot be done. You can "group" by Servicer_Code__c, but that requires you to use an aggregate statement, as Adrian pointed out. You really do not want to SUM or AVG your PolicyIds  :-)

There is some capability to nest query results in SOQL, but only if you are using two objects with a formal relationship.  See the Left Outer Join example here  [SOQL relationships](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/A_Deeper_look_at_SOQL_and_Relationship_Queries_on_Force.com)

> Left Outer Join
>
> Problem: Find all positions with their related list of applications.
>
> Again, we would like to list the positions regardless of whether there
>   is a related application or not.
>
> SOQL Query:
>
> SELECT Name, (SELECT Name FROM Job_Applications__r) FROM Position__c

Answer (score 2):

If you want unique values for that one field, you should `GROUP BY` only that field:

```
SELECT ... FROM Policy__c WHERE ...
GROUP BY Servicer_Code__c
```

You can also build a collection of unique values after the fact using a `Set`:

```
Set<String> codes = new Set<String>();
for (AggregateResult aggregate : [/* query from OP */])
{
    //existing logic
    codes.add((String)aggregate.get('sc'));
}
```

Comment: not sure if this is a by-product or limitation of using AggregateResult but I receive this error > "Field must be grouped or aggregated: Id"...  Thanks!

Comment: @SFDCCrystalCo You can only get data that is grouped or aggregated, just like it says. If a field is in your `SELECT` clause, it must be in your `GROUP BY` clause or wrapped in an operation (`MAX`, `MIN`, etc). You have to think hard about what data you actually need. It's hard to say what to strip out without more context.

Comment: The end product is list of records displayed within a Visualforce page component - you actually helped me out with this!  My query is (correctly) returning a list unique Policy ID's but rather I want to group the results by the Servicer_Code__c field instead.  It's looking like this is cannot be easily done within the boundaries of a SOQL query!